# Why does the blur only work half on a navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a navbar in react:

```
<Navbar key="md" expand="md" fixed="top" className="navbarComponent mb-3 bellefair">
            <Container fluid>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls={`offcanvasNavbar-expand-md`} />
                <Navbar.Offcanvas
                    id={`offcanvasNavbar-expand-md`}
                    aria-labelledby={`offcanvasNavbarLabel-expand-md`}
                    placement="end"
                >
                    <Offcanvas.Header closeButton/>
                    <Offcanvas.Body>
                        <Nav className="justify-content-start flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                            <Nav.Link href="#action1" style={{color: "white"}}>Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#action2" style={{color: "white"}}>Link</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Offcanvas.Body>
                </Navbar.Offcanvas>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
```

And i want that navbar to be blur. I have already done this, but when I am on the phone and the burger menu is activated, the menu remains white, it does not become as blurry.
I try to change css file, but without any result.

This is my CSS:

```
.navbarComponent {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40%;
    height: 75px;

    backdrop-filter: blur(10px) !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    margin-left: 80% !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url('../../assets/icons/NavbarBurger.png') !important;
}

.btn-close {
    --bs-btn-close-opacity: 1 !important;
    background-image: url('../../assets/icons/NavbarButton.png') !important;
}

.offcanvas-body, .offcanvas-header {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px) !important;
    background-color: #0B0D17 !important;
}
```

I tried to modify the css, but it didn't work. It works partially, that is, the navbar appears blurred exactly as it should, but on the phone the image is completely white, and the blur does not work.

Comment: It's unrelated, but you're really misusing `!important` a lot in your code - you should remove them, you don't need them and they'll only cause you problems down the road.

Comment: Please post a screenshot - it's hard to visualize what you're describing.